# Text not rendered properly in eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

In my eclipse editor, when I type the following program,

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void render()
    {
        render(); // this method is always displayed as empty rectangles.
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse Helios, in Ubuntu. The JDK used is JDK 1.6.0_25

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No idea. Maybe it's to make you avoid the infinite recursive loop cause by this code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your default font doesn't support Italics properly (references to statics are colored and *italicized*).  Go to the **Colors and Fonts** preference page and change the Text font to something else.